# Linq query for only the first N rows for each unique ID

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I have an `IQueryable` that will return a datatype with an `ID` property (column).

I want to further filter my query (*I don't want to evaluate the query*) as follows:

For each unique `ID` from the main query, I want to `Take(n)`, where `n` is some arbitrary number.

*That is, I want to only keep the first `n` rows for each unique ID.*

I can get the distinct `ID`'s...

```
var ids = query.Select(q => q.ID).Distinct();
```

and I can `Take(n)` with the rest of them, but I'm stumped on connecting the two:

```
query = query.<FOR EACH DISTINCT ID>.Take(n);
```

**The accepted answer works, but is slow for a large table. I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743696/efficient-query-for-only-the-first-n-rows-for-each-unique-id) as a follow-up.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
query = query.GroupBy(q => q.ID).SelectMany(g => g.Take(n));
```

The `GroupBy` brings together the records with identical `ID`s, letting you process them as a group; `SelectMany` takes each group, limits the number of its members to `n`, and puts the results back into one flat list.